# How to enable kerberos authetication when connecting to secure hbase cluster

Tags: security, hadoop, hbase, apache-phoenix

Has anybody seen following messages while connection to secure hbase cluster using phoenix:

```
15/08/25 23:04:49 DEBUG ipc.AbstractRpcClient: Use SIMPLE authentication for service MasterService, sasl=false
15/08/25 23:04:49 DEBUG ipc.AbstractRpcClient: Connecting to nnn-hdp-sa-********/10.99.40.213:60000
15/08/25 23:04:49 DEBUG ipc.AbstractRpcClient: Use SIMPLE authentication for service MasterService, sasl=false
15/08/25 23:04:49 DEBUG ipc.AbstractRpcClient: Connecting to nnn-hdp-sa-********/10.99.40.213:60000
15/08/25 23:04:49 DEBUG ipc.AbstractRpcClient: Use SIMPLE authentication for service MasterService, sasl=false
15/08/25 23:04:49 DEBUG ipc.AbstractRpcClient: Connecting to nnn-hdp-sa-********/10.99.40.213:60000
```

It seems it is using simple authentication to connect to hbase master service? How can we make it use kerberos authentication?

Answer (score 1):

Check this out: https://phoenix.apache.org/server.html.

> The Phoenix Query Server provides an alternative means for interaction
>   with Phoenix and HBase. Soon this will enable access from environments
>   other than the JVM.

Specific Phoenix configuration (I presume you already have a Phoenix Kerberos principal):

```
hbase.security.authentication   When set to "kerberos", the server will attempt to log in before initiating Phoenix connections.    Specified hbase-default.xml
phoenix.queryserver.keytab.file The key to look for keytab file.    unset
phoenix.queryserver.kerberos.principal  The kerberos principal to use when authenticating.  unset
phoenix.queryserver.dns.nameserver  The DNS hostname    default
phoenix.queryserver.dns.interface   The name of the network interface to query for DNS. default
```